# ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute isn't working for ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, servercontrols, partial-postback

I'm creating a server control, which has a property that I am adding as an expando attribute. It works on the initial page load, but after a partial postback, it stops working. My expando attribute is gone.

The class is a class derived from a telerik RadButton.

This is what I am doing in the overridden PreRender method:

```
Dim radContextMenu As RadContextMenu = Parent.FindControl(ContextMenuID)
If radContextMenu IsNot Nothing Then
  'register the name of our context menu so we can access it from javascript
  ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute(Me, Me.ClientID, "ContextMenuClientID", radContextMenu.ClientID, False)
End If
```

As you can see, I'm using ScriptManager, which is supposed to work in partial postback senarios (and it has for other projects of mine) but RegisterExpandoAttribute doesn't seem to work here. Also, I have stepped through the code as well and determined that radContextMenu is indeed found by FindControl.

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appriciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved similar issue by adding check for page's `ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack` property. When it is set to `false` you should use `<control>.Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute` method.

I ended up with new extension method for `Control` containing this logic:

```
public static void RegisterExpandoAttribute(this Control control, HtmlTextWriter writer, string attributeName, string attributeValue, bool encode = false)
{
    var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(control.Page);
    if (scriptManager != null && scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
        ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute(control, control.ClientID, attributeName, attributeValue, encode);
    else
        control.Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(control.ClientID, attributeName, attributeValue, encode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, when I tried this approach, the same issue occurred. If I am in an async postback, the problem i was originally having is that ScriptManager.RegisterExpandoAttribute is not adding the attribute. After an ajax request, I lose my attribute and the script manager wont re-add it. What i'm thinking I might do is register a startup script and just add the attribute manually, which I'm pretty sure would work, but it would be nice to find out why RegisterExpandoAttribute wont do it for me.

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. I'm not aware about Telerik RadButton inheritance hierarchy but as you can know expando attributes are registered in overriden `AddAttributesToRender` method of the `WebControl`. Possibly, telerik have same thing or if they are also inheriting from `WebControl` then you can try overriding `AddAttributesToRender`.

Comment: I will give that a try when I get a chance

Comment: By adding

`Dim radContextMenu As RadContextMenu = Parent.FindControl(ContextMenuID)
        If radContextMenu IsNot Nothing Then
            writer.AddAttribute("ContextMenuClientID", radContextMenu.ClientID)
        End If`

I was able to get it working. I had to modify my JS a little, to use element.getAttribute("ContextMenuClientID") instead, but works the same and I like it better than my hack :)